EXPRESS-HANDLEBARS
Buen día, tengo una duda, con express-handlebars
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: require('./lib/handlebars')
}));

tengo esto en nodejs pero me devuelve un error diciendo lo siguiente:
exphbs is not a function

qué puede ser?

exphbs is not a function
Este error indica que estás usando () sobre un valor que no es una función.
Según la documentación de express-handlebars la forma de importar el template engine es esta:
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';

Esto nos indica que el módulo express-handlebars no exporta la función engine directamente, sino que exporta un objeto tal que una de sus propiedades es engine, algo así como esto:
export default {
    ngine
}

Solución
Importa con require el objeto  que exporta express-handlebars y después accede a la propiedad engine del siguiente modo:
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const engine = handlebars.engine


Este es el ejemplo adaptado de la documentación para usar require
const express = require('express')
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const engine = handlebars.engine
const app = express()

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);

Para este ejemplo, debes tener la carpeta views de la siguiente manera:
.
├── app.js
└── views
    ├── home.handlebars
    └── layouts
        └── main.handlebars


Muchas gracias, ha quedado solucionado
